# ios and rubber band

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have looked at [Rubber Band](http://www.breakfastquay.com/rubberband/) and even downloaded it onto my laptop. It is really a unix based program (so can run on OSX) but it dos require some prerequisites (e.i libsamplerate and libfftw3). Also most of the commands for actually making the program are run on a command line possibly in a Terminal or something similar. I need to have to ability to check and change the BPM rate of an audio file (specifically .cat, .wav, and .mp3 however the more files the bettwe obviously). However i need to do this for the Iphone (IOS) which is an integrated platform of OSX. Of course not everything that can be run on a mac can be run on an iphone, but does anyone know how to import Rubber Band into my application or an alternative to the main goal?

Answer (score 0):

Rubber Band is open source: which means the code is freely available for you to use.

You have probably downloaded the **command line utility** pre-compiled binary that's available. What you want instead is to download the **source code** (the first link on the download page here: http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/).

You can then take this source code and integrate it via XCode. Rubber Band is written in C++, so if you're not familiar with that language it may be a bit of a pain: but certainly achievable.

Comment: unfortunately i am not completely familiar with C++, I am very familiar with objective C, but it is my first (an only) C based language. Could you maybe give me a lead, link, or very brief description on how to do this